# Convert an NSDate to local timezone, check if 'today' or 'tomorrow' and get the date in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know similar questions have been asked before, but my situation is slightly different and I've been trying to get a solution for it.

I have my code doing so:

```
NSDate *messageDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time / 1000];

NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:messageDate];

NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:messageDate];

NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;

// get final date in LocalTimeZone
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:messageDate];

static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
static dispatch_once_t sOnce = 0;
dispatch_once(&sOnce, ^{
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
});

[formatter setDateFormat:format];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *absTime = [formatter stringFromDate:destinationDate];
```

Now I have a problem here. Eg:

```
time = 1432028287411
messageDate = 2015-05-19 09:38:07 +0000
(NSInteger) currentGMTOffset = -25200
(NSInteger) gmtOffset = 0
destinationDate = 2015-05-19 02:38:07 +0000
absTime = Mon, May 18
```

As you can see, the `NSString` is not consistent with the date that I'm explicitly converting to `local timezone`. This is also causing problems when I use 'isDateInToday' method. What am I missing here? Note: My local time zone is set to `PST`.

Comment: I think the code behaves as expected. Your subtraction created Tue, 2:38AM GMT, which is Mon, 7:38PM PDT, which is what your absTime shows. Perhaps it would help if you could explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to get the time in local time zone, which is what all the code is doing. But, looks like it is not converting it. I want the time to be displayed i n local time zone which should end up as you suggested. But on the browser it shows as Tue, 2:38AM which should be PDT. Hence the confusion

Comment: Ok, I think you are converting it twice. Look at my example below.

Comment: Thanks @MirekE. Your suggestion works. However, I do remember doing something like this before I changed my code to this more convoluted logic. There was one or two cases with GMT time getting messed up but this should probably take care of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting this is Swift, but since the problem is about correct usage of the API rather than Objective-C, this will hopefully serve the same role as pseudo code and will be useful for you. Basically, you are converting the time twice, once by subtracting the interval and once by specifying TZ in the formatter.

Convert to NSDate

```
let time:NSTimeInterval = 1432028287411/1000
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: time)
```

Formatter to display the result in UTC/GMT

```
let utcFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
utcFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
utcFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss zzz"
```

Formatter to display the result in current time zone, i.e. PDT

```
let currentTzFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
currentTzFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
currentTzFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss zzz"
```

Show GMT/UTC time

```
utcFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Show PDT (local TZ) time

```
currentTzFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Check if the date is today (in local TZ)

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.isDateInToday(date) <- will show false today, because it is 26th today, not 19th, but will work correctly with today's date.
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. And the code in the question is Objective-C. Answers should be posted in the appropriate language.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with your code is the time zone. Here is a rough outline of how it should look:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-09-02 17:49:54";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
NSLog(@"%@", [date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:tz locale:nil]);
```